# Animate div in another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following. This will animate the div onClick. I want the div with menu list and image  to go into the yellow div instead of going into the white space. Hope you understood. Are there any ways to achieve this?? [This is what I have](http://jsfiddle.net/SSLbA/1/)

```
        <div id="content">
          <div id="pageNav"  style="z-index:9999; position:relative;height:180px;">
            <button id="showmenu" type="button">Hide menu</button>
            <div class="sidebarmenu" style="position: absolute;">
               Menu List
               <img class="image" src="http://www.glamquotes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/smile.jpg">
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#showmenu {
background: #d2d2d2;
border-radius: 35px;
border: none;
height:30px;
width:140px;
font-weight:bold;
position:relative;
left:10px;
top:10px;
margin-bottom:15px;
}
#content{
background:yellow;
height:300px;
width:300px;
margin-left:30px;
}
.image{
height:90px;
width:90px;
}
.sidebarmenu{
background:pink;
height:150px;
width:150px;
text-color:white;
}
```

jQuery

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $('#showmenu').click(function() {
               var hidden = $('.sidebarmenu').data('hidden');
               $('#showmenu').text(hidden ? 'Hide Menu' : 'Show Menu');
               if(hidden){
                   $('.sidebarmenu,.image').animate({
                   left: '0px'
               },500)
               } else {
                   $('.sidebarmenu,.image').animate({
                   left: '-210px'
               },500)
              }
              $('.sidebarmenu,.image').data("hidden", !hidden);

                });
            });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add overflow hidden to your `#content` :

```
#content {
  background: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SSLbA/2/)**

The reason we add overflow hidden is that in our current animation we're moving it to the left, making it go outside of the perimeter of the containing element (#content here), when overflow isn't set to hidden it's default value is `visible`.

I recommend reading this [article](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning) to have a better understanding of absolute positioning.

Comment: @PatsyIssa got it. that's why I deleted the comment :-)
Can you explain why to add overflow:hidden in the answer too?

Comment: @AnushaHoney Sure thing, i ll add it to the answer now. Lunch is here brb >.<

Comment: @AnushaHoney Actually `overflow:hidden;` will hide the content which overflow from the containing div.So here on animation your menu is going outside the `#content`.When it is hidden this gives the illusion effect of going inside the `#content` div.But the truth is it is hiding. Am i Correct @Patsy Issa

Comment: @AnushaHoney Added the explanation to the answer.